# How to undecorate a window with xprop

Tags: window-decorations

I've checked that when a window goes undecorated (by clicking on the icon and clicking on "Un/Decorate"), the property `_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) =` changes from empty to storing a value `_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _OB_WM_STATE_UNDECORATED`. I've also managed to change that value from the command line:

```
xprop -id 0x02c00002 -f _NET_WM_STATE 32a -set _NET_WM_STATE _OB_WM_STATE_UNDECORATED
```

by doing so, the windows does not go undecorated, the property actually changes its value, but it stays unaltered.

My question is: how to make the window undecorated with a similar `xprop` command?, what is left in the procedure above?

And also: what's the meaning of `-f _NET_WM_STATE 32a` in the command that alters the value?

Update: I'm using `wmctrl`, but can't see how to perform the action with the `-b` option, from the man: `The supported property names are modal, sticky, maximized_vert, maximized_horz, shaded,  skip_taskbar, skip_pager, hidden, fullscreen, above and below`.

Comment: You can't make a window undecorated by just changing the property, you have to tell the window manager about it (the WM in WM_STATE means "window manager). If you can do that at all depends on the window manager.

Comment: @dirkt Question updated. Can't use WMs like `openbox`, since the `--replace` command does not work properly when changing from one WM to another.

Comment: @nightcod3r I have the exact situation. Did you find anything that works with xprop or wmctrl? The given answer doesn't work on arch + openbox

Comment: @ROAR, actually, I had to do it with a Python script, providing the window PID as an argument: `#! /usr/bin/python2
  import sys, getopt
  import gtk.gdk
  w = gtk.gdk.window_foreign_new( int(sys.argv[1], 16) )
  ## set decorations to false
  w.set_decorations( 0 )
  #@ toggle between 0 and 1
  gtk.gdk.window_process_all_updates()
  gtk.gdk.flush()`

Comment: @nightcod3r I went with another option too... I added a shortcut for `ToggleDecorations` in openbox configuration. Then send the shortcut key to the window with `xdotool`. Thanks for taking the time to answer me though.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try another format ?

```
xprop -id 0x02c00002  -f _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32c \
          -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS '0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0'
```

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: This worked to for me too :) .